# Как же ставить ударение в словах "звонарь" и "звонит"?

Tags: фонетика

Попалась удивившая меня информация, что якобы правильно говорить не "звонАрь", а "звОнарь", и он в колокол не "звонИт", а "звОнит". Это правда?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Странная информация! Правильно только звонАрь (звонарЯ, звонарЮ, звонарЁм, о звонарЕ; звонарИ, звонарЕй, ... о звонарЯх). И колокол звонИт! Глагол звонИть имеет следующую парадигму: звонЮ, звонИшь, звонИт, звонИм, звонИте, звонЯт. (Новый орфоэпический словарь Т.Ф.Ивановой)